# Open A New Document With A Layer In Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I have technically designed a website in Adobe Photoshop and would like to be able to make new documents in Photoshop using the layers. I do know that you can copy and paste images from the web, screenshots etc, and the document will open up with those dimensions. Which makes dragging and dropping and or copy-and-pasting easier. I just want to be able to have the exact dimensions of the images. Anybody know how to open a new document using a layer?

Thank you, Aaron

Comment: Does the new document need to be constrained to the image dimensions, or can it carry over the parent canvas size?

Answer (score 3):

To make a new document from a layer, just:

1. Right-Click on the Layer.
2. Select
   "Duplicate Layer..."
3. In the
   Destination > Document select "New".

If you have the original canvas size and you want just the image size, just:

1. Go to IMAGE (on the top menu)
2. And then "TRIM"
3. Click "Based on Transparent Pixels" and make sure all sides of are ticked.
4. Click OK.

Comment: I arrived here looking for a way to do this with a hotkey solution. Its a very common process that we all do everyday. Any suggestions?